# How to download files to the Documents Folder in iOS 8 on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, download, ios8, documents

In my App I download some files and save them in the Documents Folder.
This worked under iOS 7 without any problems.
But now under iOS8 the files seam not to be saved anymore.

Here is the old method which worked unter iOS 7:

```
-(void)downloadMediaFile: (NSString*)url{
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url];
NSString *theFilename = [fileUrl lastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"FILE NAME IS %@",theFilename);
NSData *mediaData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:theFilename];

[mediaData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"FINAL PATH %@",filePath);
}
```

I tried something different in iOS8 but without success:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [utilities applicationDocumentsDirectory];

-(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
return urlString;
}
```

Comment: Any solution yet? I have a very similar problem